# How can I impersonate all current sessions on the target computer?

Tags: c#, console, windows-services, console-application, .net-6.0

I have this piece of code:

```
public static void Registrar(string caminho, Estilo estilo)
{
    try
    {
        RegistryKey registryKey = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(@"Control Panel\Desktop", true);

        switch (estilo)
        {
            case Estilo.Fill:
                registryKey.SetValue(@"WallpaperStyle", 10.ToString());
                registryKey.SetValue(@"TileWallpaper", 0.ToString());
                break;
            case Estilo.Fit:
                registryKey.SetValue(@"WallpaperStyle", 6.ToString());
                registryKey.SetValue(@"TileWallpaper", 0.ToString());
                break;
            case Estilo.Span:
                registryKey.SetValue(@"WallpaperStyle", 22.ToString());
                registryKey.SetValue(@"TileWallpaper", 0.ToString());
                break;
            case Estilo.Stretch:
                registryKey.SetValue(@"WallpaperStyle", 2.ToString());
                registryKey.SetValue(@"TileWallpaper", 0.ToString());
                break;
            case Estilo.Tile:
                registryKey.SetValue(@"WallpaperStyle", 0.ToString());
                registryKey.SetValue(@"TileWallpaper", 1.ToString());
                break;
            case Estilo.Center:
                registryKey.SetValue(@"WallpaperStyle", 0.ToString());
                registryKey.SetValue(@"TileWallpaper", 0.ToString());
                break;
            default:
                registryKey.SetValue(@"WallpaperStyle", 10.ToString());
                registryKey.SetValue(@"TileWallpaper", 0.ToString());
                break;
        }

        SystemParametersInfo(SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER, 0, caminho, SPIF_UPDATEINIFILE | SPIF_SENDWININICHANGE);
    }
    catch
    {
        throw;
    }
}
```

Context: I need send a program and execute it on the target machine (many on my organization), but I have to send it throw LogMeIn, and it require an User/Password to login and copy/execute this program on target.

The problem: As LogMeIn logged on the target and this application is executed, this piece of code change the WallPapper only for the user that LogMeIn logged in. I make a search and found that I can impersionate any account on the target computer, but I need to impersonate from the current sessions on the computer.

The question: How can I get all the live sessions and impersonate, to execute this piece of code for all the sessions?

**EDIT**

This is the actual solution, but I'm getting the "Unable impersonate" error.

```
while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
{
    IntPtr usuarioSessaoToken = IntPtr.Zero;

    Dictionary<string, IntPtr> usuariosLogados = new Dictionary<string, IntPtr>();

    foreach (Process process in Process.GetProcesses())
    {
        try
        {
            OpenProcessToken(process.Handle, TOKEN_QUERY, out usuarioSessaoToken);

            if (usuarioSessaoToken != null && usuarioSessaoToken != IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                using (WindowsIdentity windowsIdentity = new WindowsIdentity(usuarioSessaoToken))
                {
                    if (!usuariosLogados.ContainsKey(windowsIdentity.Name) &&
                        !windowsIdentity.Name.Contains("NT ") &&
                        !windowsIdentity.Name.Contains("Font ") &&
                        !windowsIdentity.Name.Contains("Window "))
                    {
                        usuariosLogados.Add(windowsIdentity.Name, usuarioSessaoToken);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch
        {
        }
    }

    foreach (var usuarioLogado in usuariosLogados)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", usuarioLogado.Value, usuarioLogado.Key);

        using (WindowsIdentity windowsIdentity = new WindowsIdentity(usuarioLogado.Value))
        {
            WindowsIdentity.RunImpersonated(windowsIdentity.AccessToken, () =>
            {
                _OnSite.InicializarProcesso(modeloConfiguracao);
            });
        }

        if (usuarioLogado.Value != IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            CloseHandle(usuarioLogado.Value);
        }
    }

    if (usuarioSessaoToken != IntPtr.Zero)
    {
        CloseHandle(usuarioSessaoToken);
    }

    ArquivoLog.EscreverInformacao("PROCESSO DE GERENCIAMENTO INTERNO FINALIZADO.");
    ArquivoLog.EscreverInformacao("ENTRARÁ EM ESPERA DE TRÊS (3) HORAS.");

    await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromHours(3), stoppingToken);
}
```

Any solution?

Comment: This sounds more like something you would do with a group policy instead of logging in as a user and trying to impersonate users. The first you have for free assuming your many machines are domain joined.

Comment: We can't do it by group policy and that's why we come up with this solution.

Comment: "The first you have for free assuming your many machines are domain joined." > This sentence does not make any sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found an anwser:

The class responsable, **Impersonate**:

```
const UInt32 SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED = 0x00000002;
const Int32 ANYSIZE_ARRAY = 1;
const string SE_INCREASE_QUOTA_NAME = "SeIncreaseQuotaPrivilege";
const int ERROR_NOT_ALL_ASSIGNED = 1300;

[DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
static extern bool LookupPrivilegeValue(string lpSystemName, string lpName, out LUID lpLuid);

[DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
static extern bool AdjustTokenPrivileges(IntPtr TokenHandle, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)] bool DisableAllPrivileges, ref TOKEN_PRIVILEGES NewState, UInt32 Zero, IntPtr Null1, IntPtr Null2);

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern IntPtr GetShellWindow();

[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
static extern uint GetWindowThreadProcessId(IntPtr hWnd, out uint lpdwProcessId);

[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
static extern IntPtr OpenProcess(ProcessAccessFlags dwDesiredAccess, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)] bool bInheritHandle, uint dwProcessId);

[DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
static extern bool OpenProcessToken(IntPtr ProcessHandle, TokenAccessFlags DesiredAccess, out IntPtr TokenHandle);

[DllImport("advapi32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
extern static bool DuplicateTokenEx(IntPtr hExistingToken, TokenAccessFlags dwDesiredAccess, IntPtr lpThreadAttributes, SECURITY_IMPERSONATION_LEVEL ImpersonationLevel, TOKEN_TYPE TokenType, out IntPtr phNewToken);

[DllImport("kernel32.dll", EntryPoint = "CloseHandle", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
extern static bool CloseHandle(IntPtr handle);

[DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
static extern bool CreateProcessAsUserW(IntPtr hToken, string lpApplicationName, string lpCommandLine, IntPtr lpProcessAttributes, IntPtr lpThreadAttributes, bool bInheritHandles, CreationFlags dwCreationFlags, IntPtr lpEnvironment, string lpCurrentDirectory, ref STARTUPINFO lpStartupInfo, out PROCESS_INFORMATION lpProcessInformation);

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
struct LUID
{
    public uint LowPart;
    public int HighPart;
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
struct LUID_AND_ATTRIBUTES
{
    public LUID Luid;
    public UInt32 Attributes;
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
struct STARTUPINFO
{
    public Int32 cb;
    public string lpReserved;
    public string lpDesktop;
    public string lpTitle;
    public Int32 dwX;
    public Int32 dwY;
    public Int32 dwXSize;
    public Int32 dwYSize;
    public Int32 dwXCountChars;
    public Int32 dwYCountChars;
    public Int32 dwFillAttribute;
    public Int32 dwFlags;
    public Int16 wShowWindow;
    public Int16 cbReserved2;
    public IntPtr lpReserved2;
    public IntPtr hStdInput;
    public IntPtr hStdOutput;
    public IntPtr hStdError;
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
struct PROCESS_INFORMATION
{
    public IntPtr hProcess;
    public IntPtr hThread;
    public int dwProcessId;
    public int dwThreadId;
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
struct SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES
{
    public int nLength;
    public IntPtr lpSecurityDescriptor;
    public bool bInheritHandle;
}

struct TOKEN_PRIVILEGES
{
    public UInt32 PrivilegeCount;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = ANYSIZE_ARRAY)]
    public LUID_AND_ATTRIBUTES[] Privileges;
}

[Flags()]
enum ProcessAccessFlags : int
{
    AllAccess = CreateThread | DuplicateHandle | QueryInformation | SetInformation | Terminate | VMOperation | VMRead | VMWrite | Synchronize,
    CreateThread = 0x2,
    DuplicateHandle = 0x40,
    QueryInformation = 0x400,
    SetInformation = 0x200,
    Terminate = 0x1,
    VMOperation = 0x8,
    VMRead = 0x10,
    VMWrite = 0x20,
    Synchronize = 0x100000
}

[Flags()]
enum TokenAccessFlags : int
{
    STANDARD_RIGHTS_REQUIRED = 0x000F0000,
    STANDARD_RIGHTS_READ = 0x00020000,
    TOKEN_ASSIGN_PRIMARY = 0x0001,
    TOKEN_DUPLICATE = 0x0002,
    TOKEN_IMPERSONATE = 0x0004,
    TOKEN_QUERY = 0x0008,
    TOKEN_QUERY_SOURCE = 0x0010,
    TOKEN_ADJUST_PRIVILEGES = 0x0020,
    TOKEN_ADJUST_GROUPS = 0x0040,
    TOKEN_ADJUST_DEFAULT = 0x0080,
    TOKEN_ADJUST_SESSIONID = 0x0100,
    TOKEN_READ = (STANDARD_RIGHTS_READ | TOKEN_QUERY),
    TOKEN_ALL_ACCESS = (STANDARD_RIGHTS_REQUIRED | TOKEN_ASSIGN_PRIMARY | TOKEN_DUPLICATE | TOKEN_IMPERSONATE | TOKEN_QUERY | TOKEN_QUERY_SOURCE | TOKEN_ADJUST_PRIVILEGES | TOKEN_ADJUST_GROUPS | TOKEN_ADJUST_DEFAULT | TOKEN_ADJUST_SESSIONID)
}

[Flags]
enum CreationFlags
{
    CREATE_BREAKAWAY_FROM_JOB = 0x01000000,
    CREATE_DEFAULT_ERROR_MODE = 0x04000000,
    CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE = 0x00000010,
    CREATE_NEW_PROCESS_GROUP = 0x00000200,
    CREATE_NO_WINDOW = 0x08000000,
    CREATE_PROTECTED_PROCESS = 0x00040000,
    CREATE_PRESERVE_CODE_AUTHZ_LEVEL = 0x02000000,
    CREATE_SEPARATE_WOW_VDM = 0x00001000,
    CREATE_SUSPENDED = 0x00000004,
    CREATE_UNICODE_ENVIRONMENT = 0x00000400,
    DEBUG_ONLY_THIS_PROCESS = 0x00000002,
    DEBUG_PROCESS = 0x00000001,
    DETACHED_PROCESS = 0x00000008,
    EXTENDED_STARTUPINFO_PRESENT = 0x00080000
}

enum SECURITY_IMPERSONATION_LEVEL
{
    SecurityAnonymous,
    SecurityIdentification,
    SecurityImpersonation,
    SecurityDelegation
}

enum TOKEN_TYPE
{
    TokenPrimary = 1,
    TokenImpersonation
}

public void ExecutarComoUsuario(string caminhoExecutavel, string[] argumentos)
{
    try
    {
        IntPtr currentToken;
        int lastError;

        if (!OpenProcessToken(Process.GetCurrentProcess().Handle, TokenAccessFlags.TOKEN_ADJUST_PRIVILEGES, out currentToken))
        {
            lastError = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
            throw new Win32Exception(lastError, "HOUVE UM ERRO AO RECUPERAR O TOKEN DO PROCESSO ATUAL.");
        }

        LUID myLUID;

        if (!LookupPrivilegeValue(null, SE_INCREASE_QUOTA_NAME, out myLUID))
        {
            lastError = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
            throw new Win32Exception(lastError, "HOUVE UM ERRO AO RECUPERAR OS VALORES DE \"PRIVILEGIO\" ATUAL.");
        }

        TOKEN_PRIVILEGES myTokenPrivileges;

        myTokenPrivileges.PrivilegeCount = 1;
        myTokenPrivileges.Privileges = new LUID_AND_ATTRIBUTES[1];
        myTokenPrivileges.Privileges[0].Attributes = SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED;
        myTokenPrivileges.Privileges[0].Luid = myLUID;

        if (!AdjustTokenPrivileges(currentToken, false, ref myTokenPrivileges, 0, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero))
        {
            lastError = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
            throw new Win32Exception(lastError, "HOUVE UM ERRO AO AJUSTAR OS \"PRIVILEGIOS\" ATUAIS.");
        }

        CloseHandle(currentToken);
        lastError = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();

        if (lastError == ERROR_NOT_ALL_ASSIGNED)
        {
            lastError = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
            throw new Win32Exception(lastError, "HOUVE UM ERRO \"GENÉRICO\".");
        }

        Process processExplorer = Process.GetProcessesByName("explorer").FirstOrDefault();

        if (processExplorer == null || processExplorer == default(Process))
        {
            lastError = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
            throw new Win32Exception(lastError, "HOUVE UM ERRO AO RECUPERAR O PROCESSO \"EXPLORER\".");
        }
        else
        {
            uint processID = uint.Parse(processExplorer.Id.ToString());

            IntPtr processHandle = OpenProcess(ProcessAccessFlags.QueryInformation, true, processID);

            if (processHandle == IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                lastError = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
                throw new Win32Exception(lastError, "HOUVE UM ERRO AO ABRIR O PROCESSO \"EXPLORER\".");
            }

            IntPtr explorerProcessToken;

            TokenAccessFlags tokenAccess = TokenAccessFlags.TOKEN_QUERY | TokenAccessFlags.TOKEN_ASSIGN_PRIMARY | TokenAccessFlags.TOKEN_DUPLICATE | TokenAccessFlags.TOKEN_ADJUST_DEFAULT | TokenAccessFlags.TOKEN_ADJUST_SESSIONID;

            if (!OpenProcessToken(processHandle, tokenAccess, out explorerProcessToken))
            {
                lastError = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
                throw new Win32Exception(lastError, "HOUVE UM ERRO AO RECUPERAR O TOKEN DO PROCESSO \"EXPLORER\".");
            }

            IntPtr newPrimaryToken;
            if (!DuplicateTokenEx(explorerProcessToken, tokenAccess, IntPtr.Zero, SECURITY_IMPERSONATION_LEVEL.SecurityImpersonation, TOKEN_TYPE.TokenPrimary, out newPrimaryToken))
            {
                lastError = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
                throw new Win32Exception(lastError);
                throw new Win32Exception(lastError, "HOUVE UM ERRO AO DUPLICAR O TOKEN DO PROCESSO \"EXPLORER\".");
            }

            STARTUPINFO startupInfo = new STARTUPINFO();
            startupInfo.cb = Marshal.SizeOf(startupInfo);
            startupInfo.lpDesktop = "";

            PROCESS_INFORMATION processInfo = new PROCESS_INFORMATION();

            if (!CreateProcessAsUserW(newPrimaryToken, caminhoExecutavel, caminhoExecutavel + " " + argumentos, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero, false, 0, IntPtr.Zero, null, ref startupInfo, out processInfo))
            {
                lastError = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
                throw new Win32Exception(lastError, "HOUVE UM ERRO AO CRIAR UM NOVO PROCESSO.");
            }

            CloseHandle(processInfo.hProcess);
            CloseHandle(processInfo.hThread);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw;
    }
}
```

You can use this class inside a service, as I did, and when you call it, you pass the path for another Console Application, in this new Console, you can interact with the Desktop.